# Count of Sums possibly using group_by

Tags: sql, mysql

Say you have a user table and an order table which references user (user has_many orders) and contains an item count field.

How could you efficiently ask "how many uses ordered how many items?"

That is, to generate something along the lines of:

```
Number of users | sum of items
-------------------------------
5 users         | 1 item
4 users         | 5 items
1 user          | 7 items
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Order tables do not generally contain Item information. that is generally in an orderDetails table, which has OrderId, ItemNumber (ItemId) unitPrice, and ItemCount... or something similar. Are you sure you're not talking about an OrderDetails table ?

Comment: The actual problem involves an installation record with a login count and a user can have many installations of an iPhone app. Phrased it in the form of users and orders because thats just such a common way of visualizing the heart of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a derived table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Number of Users`, `Sum of Items` 
FROM (
    SELECT u.UserID, SUM(ItemCount) AS `Sum of Items`
    FROM User u
    INNER JOIN Order o ON u.UserID = o.UserID
    GROUP BY u.UserID
) g
GROUP BY `Sum of Items`
```

Comment: Here the User table is unnecessary at all.